# How can I store a dictionary in a file which I can encrypt?

Tags: python, cryptography, password-encryption

I'm pretty new to Python and programming in general and am currently working on a little password manager. Thus far I have a script which can encode a txt file using the cryptography library. I am now wondering if it is possible to store information on a website or an account with a corresponding Password in the txt file or if I need to use something else than a txt file. What would you recommend?

Comment: If you can store text, then probably the easiest way would be to write to a file
<username>,<password>
then encrypt that. Then, to read it in, decrypt, and split at the comma. Make sure that neither the username or passwords have a comma in them, though

Comment: Yes, @JacobSteinebronn that is OK if you do not need significant security. However, this then allows for one "simple" crack to give access to all passwords.  Better to use salted encryption, as I wrote below.

Comment: Sure, but the question wasn't about encryption, it was about storing data. Cheers, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is convert that dict to json and encrypt the string result.
It's easy convert to dict too. What I advise you to do if you're using this only for auth, is save like a key value store. Example:

```
{
    "<user>": "<password>",
    "<user2>" : "<password2>"
}
```

On this datastruct the code will be always O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a text file.  That is not a problem. The text file will *contain encrypted text*.

Depending upon how secure and how many unique passwords, you probably want a *salted* encryption techique.

I would recommend [`passlib`](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

I will give as an example some code I recently made, and explain it (although I am not a cryptography expert):

```py
from passlib.context import CryptContext

CRYPTO_CTX = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto") # This means only use `'bcrypt'`.

@app.post("/login")
def login_user(user, db):
    db_user = crud.get_user_by_username(db, username=user.username)
    if db_user is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=400, detail=f"No username {user.username} found."
        )
    if not CRYPTO_CTX.verify(user.password, db_user.hashed_password): ## This is the essential portion
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f"Incorrect password.")
    db_user = crud.update_user(db, db_user, {"last_visit": datetime.now(timezone.utc)})
    return {"user": db_user}
```

This code is, as I said, for a website, and it is using [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/). I have removed some stuff for clarity while hopefully keeping enough context. Here is the breakdown:

1. You need to make a "Cryptographic context", which will know which hashing scheme(s) to use.

   - In my case, I am only using and allowing `'bcrypt'`, a best practice choice for 2020 (but you can choose others for flexibility).
2. I then create a `'/login'` web route, which is a URI endpoint that triggers a function.
3. That function receives `user` information from an HTTP *`POST`* that an end user submitted (and a database session).
4. The user is then searched on the database backend. Presuming she is found, the *submitted* password in the `POST` is compared to the password in the database, but that password is cryptographically protected.

Let's zoom in on that comparison:

```py
    if not CRYPTO_CTX.verify(user.password, db_user.hashed_password):
```

We are providing a **plain text string (`user.password`)** and a **hashed string** (`db_user.hashed_password`) to our `CRYPTO_CTX`s `verify` method. That is all that is needed, since the `passlib` library is doing all the heavy lifting.

---

How was the password encrypted?  That was just as easy:

```py
hashed_password = CRYPTO_CTX.hash(user.password)
```

And this does not just encrypt the password, it also [*salts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) it. In short, this means that if *somehow* the encryption were hacked, **it would only work for that one entry**. With salting, it's a two-step encryption process:

- Create a password.  Eg, `'Elderberries'`

1. Add a salt to it: `'Elderberries34(*&#arst@#!'`
2. Hash that entire thing: `'B4B6603ABC670967E99C7E7F1389E40CD16E78AD38EB1468EC2AA1E62B8BED3A'`

Comment: I am using a salt and a user created "master-password" to encrypt the file using the fernet functions from the cryptography library. The "master-password" and the salt create a key for the Fernet functions to use while encrypting the data. I think it is called AES. Is there a problem with my method and why or why not is your's superior???

Comment: @Sergeant_Keks depends on the problem you're trying to solve...  The solution Mike has posted is for validating a user's password in a web server (and doing work to protect the passwords from being leaked).  It would be good for you to clarify if this is actually what you're after.  I'm interpreting your question as a desire to write your own version of something like 1password or KeePass, if that's the case the hashing Mike is proposing wouldn't solve your problem at all and you'd need to do something else